# How to map multiple share drives upto 22 at a time using powershell?

Tags: powershell, dictionary, networking, share, drive

I have about 9000 DFS share drives in my environment. Unfortunately since there is no easy way to find out the size of each share drive with powershell i am trying to map 22 at a time and save the dump the results to csv file
So i am trying something like this

```
$csv=Import-Csv "path"
$csv.Name
foreach-object{
New-PSdrive -Root $_ -Name $driveletter}
```

The issue is that i need to start at drive letter E and go all the way to Z, obtain the drive size, unmap the current 22 drives and and then go to the next 22 and so on until the 2500th path
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: why not use the same drive letter over and over?

Comment: "find out the size of each share drive" what do you mean by this? Size of all the data on it, the size of the drive itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for what you ask (although per the comments it would be simpler to just use the same drive letter repeatedly, however this might be faster):

```
Function CleanUp-PSDrive {
    Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where { $_.Name -in (69..90 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })} | Remove-PSDrive
}

$Csv = Import-Csv "path"

$Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 } {

    New-PSdrive -Root $_ -Name ([char]$Letter) -PSProvider FileSystem

    #Do some stuff..

    if ($Letter -lt 90) 
    { 
        $Letter++ 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        CleanUp-PSDrive
        $Letter = 69
    }
} -End { CleanUp-PSDrive }
```

This uses the ASCII codes for E - Z (69 - 90) to create the lettered drives as it iterates through your CSV, when we get to letter 90 (Z) it removes all the drives using a function I declared called `CleanUp-PSDrive` and then sets $Letter to start over at 69 (E).

I created the `CleanUp-PSDrive` function because I realised that you'd need to do a clean up after the final iteration of an unknown number of remaining mapped drives. The function does this by getting them dynamically with `Get-PSDrive`. We then use the `-End` block of `ForEach-Object` to do this final cleanup.

I use the `-Begin` block of the `ForEach-Object` to declare `$Letter` for no other reason than it connects it nicely to where the counter is used.

Comment: That really helped ! How did i not think of not doing this one at a time? Guess it was because i was initially using a batch file mapping, running wmic and then un-mapping 22 shares at a time using net use /delete *. The only issue I have is is getting the path into one column and the corresponding size in the next (within the same row) in a new csv file.

Comment: You should find that with the above `New-PSDrive` is returning the path (as "root") and size information (used and free at least) as an object. As a result  you should jsut be able to put `| export-csv result.csv -notypeinformation` on the end of the above and get your results as a CSV.

Comment: or do `| select root,used | export-csv results.csv` if those properties are all you are interested in.